# Javascript video not starting on mobile Android device

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video

I'm trying to get a video to auto play on Android handheld devices. This code works on desktop computer tested in Google Chrome. What can I do to have the video autostart on mobile devices?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>vid</title>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

    function checkLoad() {
        if (myVideo.readyState === 4) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                myVideo.play();

            }, 800);
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
        }
    }

    checkLoad();
});     
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<video  id="video1" autobuffer>
        <source src="assets/video/BigBuck.m4v">
        <source src="assets/video/BigBuck.webm" type="video/webm">
        No video support
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding autoplay attribute to video tag.
like this :
<video  id="video1" autobuffer autoplay>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-play is disabled since Android SDK 17. Autoplay on most mobile platforms (Android, iOS) gets blocked to avoid poor user experiences - video should only play following a user action. But here is a workaround

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (SDK_INT > 16) {
    engine.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
}
```

by doing this you can set setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture() to false to re-enable auto-play.